# Using if () with shorter syntax

Tags: stata

Is there a way to express this with a terser syntax

```cs
if (`avgInc' > 0) {
    loc avgIncDec = "increased"
}
else {
    loc acgIncDec = "decreased"
}
```

Something like an InlineIf (iif):

```cs
loc avgInc = iif((`avgInc' > 0), "increased", "decreased")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous answer focuses helpfully on `cond()` but contains some minor errors.

```
   loc avgIncDec = cond(`avginc' > 0, "increased", "decreased")
```

Note that Stata, like many other languages, uses `=` for assignment and `==` to test for equality.

Comment: It seems many people are in need to learn about `cond()` these days :)

Comment: As mentioned in another thread, there is an introductory tutorial at http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0016

Answer (score 2):

Try `cond`

`var =  if cond(a="value","1","another value")`

if a="value" var ="1" else var = "another value"

There are other ternary operators, as well: `inrange() inlist()`